# Check that email exists with Node within API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, xmlhttprequest

**Introduction**

Ok, I have Three functions. the first two generate data for the third.

1. Gets post data (email)
2. Gets API key
3. Uses API key, User_key and email and post them to the API

**What I need**

I need the third to print the following to my console providing the email is present.

```
 else {
                    console.log("Login successful !");
                    console.log("API Key", api);
                    console.log("userKey", userkey);
                    console.log("useremail", login_email);
                    console.error("Third You have logged in !");
                }
```

**What I am getting**

> error null

I am getting this even though I post a email that exist. Dose anyone see where I am going wrong in my code ?

**Node Code**

```
var firstFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) { // may be redundant
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/test.js', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                // Get varibles from the post form
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                // res.send(email_user);
                res.send(login);
                //resolve when get the response
                resolve({
                    data_login_email: login
                });
            });
            console.error("First done");

        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};

//---------------------------------- Function to get API key from Pardot (AUTHENTICATION) ------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var secondFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                userKey: userkey,
                email: emailAdmin,
                password: password,
                DEBUG: false
            }, function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    // Authentication failed
                    console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                } else {
                    // Authentication successful
                    var api_key = client.apiKey;
                    console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                    resolve({data_api: api_key});
                }
            });
            console.error("Second done");
        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};

//---------------------------------- Function to post data to Pardot ---------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function thirdFunction(result) {
    var promise = new Promise(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            };
// Configure the request
            var api = result[1].data_api;
            var userEmail = result[0].data_login_email;
            var options = {
                url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                form: {
                    'email': userEmail,
                    'user_key': userkey,
                    'api_key': api
                }
            };

// Start the request
            request(options, function (error, response) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log("error", error);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Login successful !");
                    console.log("API Key", api);
                    console.log("userKey", userkey);
                    console.log("useremail", login_email);
                    console.error("Third You have logged in !");
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
    return promise;
}

// sequence of functions
Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
    .then(thirdFunction);
```

Comment: Your if condition is wrong `(!error && response.statusCode == 200)` should be: if there is an error or status is not 200, so `error || response.statusCode !=200`

Comment: nice, ill addend this now thanks